# Is combining $emit and $broadcast a good practice?

Tags: angularjs

I know the difference between $emit and $broadcast but I wonder if combining the two is a good practice while the hierarchy may be more complex in future?

Consider the following case:

- I have two neighbor views (lets call them Child1, Child2) inside a main view (Parent1) and I would like to pass an event between the two neighbors.
- In future, Child1, Child2 views might have future parents.

In my following example I pass "wake up" string from Child1 to Child2 (while Parent1 is the one who is passing this data).
Step by step what technically happens:

1. Child1 sends 'wake up' ($emit)
2. Parent1 catchs ($on) this event, and send to child 2 ($broadcast)
3. Child2 is informed ($on)

code:

```
function ControllerParent1($scope) {
    $scope.$on('myEmit', function(event, args) {
        $scope.$broadcast('myBroadcast', args.message); //Step2
    };
}

function ControllerChild1($scope) {
    $scope.$on('myEmit', function(event, args) {
        $scope.$emit('send', {message: 'wake up'}); //Step1
    });        
}

function ControllerChild2($scope) {
    $scope.$on('myBroadcast', function(event, args) {
        $scope.message = args.message; //Step3
    });
}
```

Now this feels to me very technical and I wonder about this practice, is it the correct way of working in angular? It may be more complicated to handle in future.

Comment: I think you should think about `$rootScope.$emit` & `$rootScope.$on` which will propagate event to `$rootScope` only.. For more details regarding performance optimization I'd highly recommend you to read on [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2807-using-rootscope-emit-as-a-performance-optimization-in-angularjs.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to future proof your application, you could use the pub/sub pattern. This way your controllers can publish events they want and subcribe to whatever event they're interested in, without strong coupling on `($scope/$rootScope).($emit/$broadcast)`.

More information on this article : http://eburley.github.io/2013/01/31/angularjs-watch-pub-sub-best-practices.html

And a sample implementation here : https://github.com/georapbox/angular-PubSub